# How can I find out which script/program/user invokes exim (and is sending spam)?

Tags: smtp, spam, exim, lsof

**The problem**

A client of mine asked me to take a look at his shared-hosting webserver for the following problem, but I'm stuck at finding out what's wrong. His server is being blacklisted by a lot of major blocking list such as CBL, Spamhaus and the blockling list from Outlook.com.

**What I've tried already**

I started by looking at the users in his DirectAdmin environment but I didn't find any users whom are sending more than couple of e-mails per day. I downloaded his exim log, took a look at the mail queue, but couldn't find anything out of the ordinary. Next thing I thought of was running `findbot.pl` from CBL, but it came up only with false-positives.

Another thing I tried was to change the `sendmail_path` in `php.ini` to log every e-mail that is being sent out via sendmail. However, everytime I changed the sendmail_path, all PHP processes started to hang. I tried different ways ([MailCatcher](http://mailcatcher.me), my own scripts), but every change made the processes hang. Really strange, but after I few tries, I moved on to the next step.

Next step: installing `lsof`and create an bash script that would print the output of `lsof -i | grep smtp` into a log file, every second, while printing the outpot of `ps auxw` to another log file every second. This gave me some valuable information, but I can't track the issue yet.

**Where I'm stuck**

So after letting it run for a couple of hours, I opened up both log files and saw a bulk of this rules:

*lsof -  logfile*

```
COMMAND     PID    USER   FD   TYPE           DEVICE  SIZE/OFF    NODE NAME
exim      10921    mail    9u  IPv4 2260427      0t0  TCP hostname-from-server.com:smtp->208.93.4.208:49711 (ESTABLISHED)
exim      10921    mail   10u  IPv4 2260427      0t0  TCP hostname-from-server.com:smtp->208.93.4.208:49711 (ESTABLISHED)
```

When I look at the logfile and search for the PID that is mentioned in the lsof logfile, I see the following lines:

*ps auxw - logfile*

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
mail      1750  0.0  0.0  59032  1320 ?        Ss   Nov28   0:01 /usr/sbin/exim -bd -q15m -oP /var/run/exim.pid
root     10909  0.0  0.0 103388   896 pts/2    S+   17:44   0:00 grep mail

mail      1750  0.0  0.0  59032  1320 ?        Ss   Nov28   0:01 /usr/sbin/exim -bd -q15m -oP /var/run/exim.pid
root     10917  0.0  0.0 103388   896 pts/2    S+   17:44   0:00 grep mail

mail      1750  0.0  0.0  59032  1320 ?        Ss   Nov28   0:01 /usr/sbin/exim -bd -q15m -oP /var/run/exim.pid
mail     10921  0.0  0.0  61112  1792 ?        S    17:44   0:00 /usr/sbin/exim -bd -q15m -oP /var/run/exim.pid
root     10923  0.0  0.0 103388   896 pts/2    S+   17:44   0:00 grep mail

mail      1750  0.0  0.0  59032  1320 ?        Ss   Nov28   0:01 /usr/sbin/exim -bd -q15m -oP /var/run/exim.pid
root     10931  0.0  0.0 103388   896 pts/2    S+   17:44   0:00 grep mail

mail      1750  0.0  0.0  59032  1320 ?        Ss   Nov28   0:01 /usr/sbin/exim -bd -q15m -oP /var/run/exim.pid
root     10939  0.0  0.0 103388   896 pts/2    S+   17:44   0:00 grep mail
```

The problem: there is nothing out of the ordinary with this line and I can't see which script, program of user called exim. When I take a look at the exim mainlog and rejectlog, I can't find the ip `208.93.4.208` nor can't I find any line at all around 17:44 (time according to the ps auxw log).

When I follow lines from the logfiles from e-mails that I send myself, I can find them in the mainlog from exim at exactly the time that is mentioned in the ps auxw log. It appears that, somehow, the spammails aren't logged in exim or are removed immediately after sending.

**My questions**

- I think I can solve my problem if I knew which script, program or user called the PID and invoked exim/mail. Does anyone have an idea?
- Is it possible that some other server, not ours, is sending out spam and is, for example, spoofing our IP-address? Maybe this is a very dumb question, but I'm curious, since it so easy to spoof headers.

**Additional information**

Via the provider-portal of Outlook.com, we managed to get one of the e-mail headers:

```
X-HmXmrOriginalRecipient: someone-who-received-our-spam@hotmail.com
X-Reporter-IP: [IP-from-some-who-flagged-as-spam]
X-Message-Guid: a2236172-9474-11e5-9c3a-00215ad6eec8
x-store-info:4r51+eLowCe79NzwdU2kR3P+ctWZsO+J
Authentication-Results: hotmail.com; spf=none (sender IP is [OUR-IP-ADDRESS]) smtp.mailfrom=minvituccia@blackberrysa.com; dkim=none header.d=blackberrysa.com; x-hmca=none header.id=minvituccia@blackberrysa.com
X-SID-PRA: minvituccia@blackberrysa.com
X-AUTH-Result: NONE
X-SID-Result: NONE
X-Message-Status: n:n
X-Message-Delivery: Vj0xLjE7dXM9MDtsPTA7YT0wO0Q9MjtHRD0yO1NDTD02
X-Message-Info: 11chDOWqoTmjqhOzvWWho/vK8oL2x1FIoEm0Tn+r3D4Vy8IHo2wUnqS07yp2Fxclyw07ONZgeH1xFUrogbJOZz8Pfl5FrUXTGgolDal8+UhiPOrwCAKsLtRr0R42oH/Du2inmiSwuWc/pY9oiWRqLA5If7jw818pUulf3QP7m+wKn2HEVHAg2VBr+OqDk1w/hWWO68tIy1BSoE8QFSPMNXh31MYdKh4mif3jAqDU+0qWqWSAxPdE/A==
Received: from [our-hostname] ([our-ip-address) by COL004-MC2F4.hotmail.com with Microsoft SMTPSVC(7.5.7601.23143);
 Thu, 26 Nov 2015 11:34:05 -0800
Return-path: <minvituccia@blackberrysa.com>
Received: (qmail 18660 invoked by uid 61081); 26 Nov 2015 20:52:03 -0000
Date: 26 Nov 2015 20:52:03 -0000
Message-ID: <20151126205203.18660.qmail@our-hostname.com>
From: "Meghann Gasparo" <minvituccia@blackberrysa.com>
To: "someone-who-received-spam-from-our-server" <someone-who-received-spam-from-our-server@hotmail.com>
Subject: You could strike all your limpid seed right into my love tunnel text me 1.970.572.00.14
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
X-OriginalArrivalTime: 26 Nov 2015 19:34:06.0061 (UTC) FILETIME=[69C119D0:01D12881]

<html><body>Throw some of your hot cum on my face, deep into my door<br>
or <a href="http://holidayextravaganza.org/wp-content/themes/">run my humps rubbed</a> once again.<br>
<a href="http://holidayextravaganza.org/wp-content/themes/">Watch my profile</a> to receive much more spicy fun or just sms right now 1-970-572-00-73</body></html>

--70969AA2-2F73-4465-8DF3-26DC57EA3967--
```

We don't use qmail as MTA. Needless to say, but the domain blackberrysa.com is not one of ours.

Comment: It doesn't have to be using exim. it's fairly easy to send mail directly.

Comment: @Iain how can I check if that is the case? The PID (10921) indicates that it is using exim.

Comment: @Iain I just received one of the e-mail headers that is received by someone, from our server. Strange thing is, the headers says that the e-mail is being sent with qmail, but we haven't installed qmail on our servers. Any possibility that the spam isn't coming from our server at all, but someone is spoofing our IP-address?

Comment: Run [maldet](https://www.rfxn.com/projects/linux-malware-detect/) on all the users' files. You're bound to turn up lots of interesting stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You could try looking at netstat to get outbound connections and filter for port 25

```
netstat -nptw | grep :25
```

You could use iptables to log outbound connections to port 25

```
iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25 -j LOG --log-prefix 'Outbound SMTP connection'
```

This produces a log record like

> Nov 29 18:15:56 hostname kernel: Outbound connectionIN= OUT=eth0 SRC=192.168.254.16 DST=192.0.2.1 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=36829 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=39355 DPT=25 WINDOW=14600 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0

Note the `SPT=39355` you can use that to search your netstat output

```
netstat -anp  | grep 39355
tcp      0    1 192.168.254.16:39355      192.0.2.1:25        SYN_SENT    13992/someprogram
```

Comment: The rule is up and running! When I have more information, I'll update the post and place a comment. I also used the `--log-uid` option, as @Law29 suggested.

Comment: Another question, netstat is coming up with a lot of rules like this: `tcp        0      0 [host-ip-address]:25           [destination-ip-address]:35597        ESTABLISHED 11932/exim`. Exim is connecting to another port than 25, which is not being monitored by the iptables rule. Why is exim connecting to another port than 25? Is this (for example) for communicating with another server that just delivered an e-mail to our server?

Answer (score 0):

You header indicates that the mail did not go through exim. The qmail "Received" header is a spammer fabrication. If you have a webserver on this server, the chances are that there is some compromised script. If you are doing NAT for other hosts, then the problem could be on the other hosts. Otherwise, you probably have a compromised server.

If you're hesitant, try

```
iptables -I OUTPUT -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 25 -j LOG --log-uid --log-prefix 'New SMTP Outbound'
```

This will log the user id of the process sending the mails.

Comment: The rule is up and running! When I have more information, I'll update the post and place a comment. Thanks for your suggestion about the `--log-uid`, that's a smart one.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend an inspection on the webserver(s) installation, where you'll probably find out lots of malicious PHP. Those PHP codes probably arrived to your webserver by someone/some-bot abusing one or more vulnerabilities of your server or its PHP files. Beware that those PHP codes may be found in many places and formats: inside a comment of a GIF or JPEG image, md5-summed, inverted, etc. Find those PHP functions and the evil `eval` and grep for them in places where you know they might not be there.